# Using Regex to extract words from sentences in Pandas for network analysis

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a Pandas dataframe where I want to extract every word from the sentences in a column and create a new dataframe where each word has its own row. In addition, the original dataframe has a rating that should be added to the new rows.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
base_network
Body    Rating
0   Very satisfied  4
1   My daughter lost 2 spoons, so I adjusted them ...   5
2   It was a fiftieth birthday present for my elde...   5
3   Love the shape, shine & elegance of the candle...   5
4   Poor description of what I was buying   3
... ... ...
476 Nice quality but it is too small, description ...   3
477 Edited 6 January 2020As you will have seen, th...   3
478 I love this piece of jewelleryIt is elegant an...   5
479 The leather cord is a little stiff…but I guess...   4
480 Unfortunately the lens is too small and not ve...   1
481 rows × 2 columns
```

I have tried to use Regex to divide the words form the sentences and store them i a new dataframe. Followed by an attempt to add the rating that matches. Using this code:

```
spaces = r"\s+"

words = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()

for rows in base_network:
    words = re.split(spaces, base_network['Body'])
    words['Rating'] = base_network['Rating']
    df = df.append(words)
    
df.head()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-4ff5191a493d> in <module>()
      5 
      6 for rows in base_network:
----> 7     words = re.split(spaces, base_network['Body'])
      8     words['Rating'] = base_network['Rating']
      9     df = df.append(words)

/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py in split(pattern, string, maxsplit, flags)
    213     and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element
    214     of the list."""
--> 215     return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
    216 
    217 def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I have tried to convert the body column to a string type but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: what is your expected output? list of word instead of sentence?

Comment: Don't loop over rows of a dataframe: Are you looking for `base_network["words"] = base_network.Body.str.split()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this satisfy your needs?

```
# split by any space
df.Body = df.Body.str.split(pat="\s")

# "explode" the list column into a long format. 
# The Rating column is recycled accordingly
df.explode("Body")
```

###### Some additional thoughts

- It might be necessary to adjust the regex to split also at any punctuation etc.
- Be careful about your input data. In line 477, "Edited 6 January 2020As you..." seems to miss a space.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. For some reason the "explode" does not happen. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: what do you mean by "does not happen"?

Comment: My bad :) I just needed to save the "explosion" like so: final_network = base_network.explode("Body")